# sharepint 2013 - how to access master page directory outside of browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

where is the physical location of master templates stored in SharePoint 2013?  I need to replace the HTML master template file which has an error on it.  As a result I cannot go to site settings, design manager, etc.. through the browser because of this error.  I would like to open up either explorer or something to replace the .htm of this master template back to the original one that does work.

thanks

Comment: You should be able to get to, and change, the masterpage via SharePoint Designer.

Comment: I don't have it installed.  Is that my only option?

Comment: Well, it's an essential tool for just about any administrator/developer/poweruser using SharePoint. I highly recommend it in your toolbox. Details here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491

Comment: I'd say that is by far the easiest option. It's as simple as installing, connecting to your site, navigating to the masterpage gallery, and changing the masterpage.

Comment: ok I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get to, and change, the masterpage via SharePoint Designer. It's an essential tool for just about any administrator/developer/poweruser using SharePoint. I highly recommend it in your toolbox. [Details here](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491).

I'd say that is by far the easiest option. It's as simple as installing, connecting to your site, navigating to the masterpage gallery, and changing the masterpage.

Comment: I did what you recommended and that fixed my problem.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can map your masterpages folder as a drive by:

1. Going to your "My Computer"
2. Click the Map Network Drive Button
3. Type in the following URL: http://your-sharepoint-site/_catalogs/masterpage
4. Edit the file as you would.

You might have to check-out and publish the file through SharePoint's interface (at the same URL).

Seeing as your masterpage is broken, you might need to resort to SPD as Mike suggested. It's possible that for your user the masterpage fix you apply will be made available letting you publish the file without SPD, though.